# Proper way of reading a page and saving it into a html file?

Tags: ruby, file

I have the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'anemone'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.findbrowsenodes.com/", :delay => 3) do |anemone|
  anemone.on_pages_like(/http:\/\/www.findbrowsenodes.com\/us\/.+\/[\d]*/) do | page |

    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page.url))

    id       = doc.at_css("#n_info #clipnode").text unless doc.at_css("#n_info #clipnode").nil?

    File.open("#{node_id}.html", "wb") do |f|
      f.write(open(page).read)
    end
  end
end
```

So I'm trying to save each URL as a html file with this:

```
    File.open("#{id}.html", "wb") do |f|
      f.write(open(page).read)
    end
```

But I get this error:

> alex@alex-K43U:~/rails/anemone$ ruby anemone.rb 
>   /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in
>   `open': can't convert Anemone::Page into String (TypeError)   from
>   /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in`
>   open'    from anemone.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'  from
>   anemone.rb:26:in`open'   from anemone.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in
>   '

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems / confusions:

1. As the error says, the `open` methods expects a `String` (i.e. the url), but you're providing an `Anemone::Page` object.

   This object has a `url` method, which you already use on line 9.
2. On line 9: `open(page.url)`

   You're already opening the page, so you could reuse that. But:
3. According to the docs http://anemone.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Anemone/Page.html `Anemone::Page` contains a `body` method that may already contain the content (I'm just guessing, haven't use or tried that library). If that's the case, there's no need to use `open`.

As I see it, the following untested code may be more like what you're looking for:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)

# [snip]

File.open("#{node_id}.html", "wb") do |f|
  f.write(page.body)
end
```